# Unable to parse SASS on CSS

Tags: tomcat, liferay, sass

Liferay started to produce multiple exceptions in log, saying `Unable to parse SASS on CSS` for many root files, like `/usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/html/css/portal/header_row.css`.

Files are present and looks ok at a glance.

Comment: delete ".sass-cache" folder under your deployed theme css folder and check error solved or not?

Comment: The error is not from my theme, but from `ROOT` application. Delete anyway?

Comment: have you tried by deleting work and temp folder? if not try it.. stop server delete mentioned folders and start server again

Comment: I tried to delete temp & work and it stops at first then appears again

Answer (score 1):

Stop your server and clean tmp dir (java and tomcat),
Get jruby.jar from liferay 6.1 M4 release,
Copy the jar in your ROOT/WEB-INF/lib folder,
Edit your portal-ext.properties to add:

```
scripting.jruby.load.paths=\
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8,\
classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared,\
classpath:/gems/chunky_png-1.2.6/lib,\
classpath:/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib,\
classpath:/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib,\
classpath:/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib,\
${java.io.tmpdir}/liferay/ruby/gems/chunky_png-1.2.6/lib,\
${java.io.tmpdir}/liferay/ruby/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib,\
${java.io.tmpdir}/liferay/ruby/gems/fssm-0.2.9/lib,\
${java.io.tmpdir}/liferay/ruby/gems/sass-3.2.1/lib
```